# SQL Exist in either TableA or TableB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I am attempting to create a script which needs a clause to check of a column value in Table 3 exists in Table 1 or Table 2

```
SELECT *      
FROM [ZERO_BALANCE].[DBO].[dat_acct_codes_REJECTIONS] ACR
WHERE [REJECTIONREASON] = 'MISSING LINKING ACCOUNT'
AND 
EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM ref_PX WHERE CAST(PX AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST(ACR.[Code] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
OR
(SELECT 1 FROM ref_DX WHERE CAST(DX AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST(ACR.[Code] AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
```

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with your query:

- Missing parentheses on the `CAST()` function (as commented by [Dale Burrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127428/dale-burrell))
- You need to repeat the `EXISTS` keyword for each condition
- Beware of operator prescedence: `OR` has lower prescendence than `AND`, so, as far as I understand your query, you `OR`ed conditions should be surrounded with parentheses.

Proper formatting helps spotting this kind of stuff.

```
SELECT *      
FROM [ZERO_BALANCE].[DBO].[dat_acct_codes_REJECTIONS] ACR
WHERE 
    [REJECTIONREASON] = 'MISSING LINKING ACCOUNT'
    AND (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM ref_PX 
            WHERE CAST(PX AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST(ACR.[Code] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        )
        OR EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM ref_DX 
            WHERE CAST(DX AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST(ACR.[Code] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
        )
    )
```